# Importing spreadsheet (pdf/xls) into Altium

Tags: altium

I have following spreadsheet in a PDF file:
[image: Signals datasheet]
How do I import it into Altium and place it on `Top Layer` in `PCB Editor`?

Comment: Best guess would be to save it as an image with transparent background (screenshot, go to paint and delete the white background) and import it as an image.

Comment: Given the accepted answer, it might be better to rename the question to "Importing table into Altium". :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have imported into Altium tables such as the one shown, but never from PDF.
One suggestion that I can give you is to try to copy and paste it into Excel, and from there copy and paste it into Altium.

I think that it was from version 16  of Altium that the import table feature was added, which not only imports the text, but also adds the border lines of each cell onto the active layer.

Worst of cases, you can re-create the table in Excel and then copy and paste it, since it doesn't contain too much text.